# Improving perfect pitch?

Tags: pitch, hearing

I've always had good pitch hearing but never perfect. Things like 1/32 tone change is hard to notice. I was wondering whether it can be improved (if you have some to begin with) to achieve "perfect pitch" or is something you're born with.

If yes, what are some effective excercises?

Not as if such precision is super practical for composing or playing but just of pure curiosity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some useful and effective exercises for training absolute pitch?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/203/what-are-some-useful-and-effective-exercises-for-training-absolute-pitch)

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing absolute pitch with simply noticing pitch differences? "Perfect pitch" usually means absolute pitch, i.e. being able to identify the pitch i.e. note name without a reference tone. It does not mean "very accurate pitch hearing". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_pitch

Comment: From what I've learned one cannot develop perfect pitch.  But perhaps that has changed.

Comment: So, perfect (absolute) pitch simply means knowing how the certain frequencies called?