# Ear training: the basics

Tags: ear-training, melody

What do I do to start ear training? I want to have to end goal of being able to hear a melody and be able to recognize the notes. But how to I get there? I don't even have a clue on where to start at all, interval training? I would also like to learn how to recognize chords as well. Help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: I'm inclined to vote this question as a duplicate, as there are already many good questions on learning [ear training](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ear-training?sort=votes&pageSize=50) on this site, such as [What are the specific progressive steps to take in basic ear training](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/what-are-the-specific-progressive-steps-to-take-in-basic-ear-training) and [What are the most effective ear training methods](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/178/what-are-the-most-effective-ear-training-methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of techniques, tips, and tricks out there beyond the "How do you get to Carnage Hall?" answer so lets start a list.  This one was super helpful for recognizing intervals (especially when I came up with my own set of mnemonics)

Comment: "Carnage Hall"... I think I've heard some performances for which that would be an appropriate venue...